# How do you create module or component,or plugin same wordpress,joomla?

Tags: components

*I want to create a cms website and i want to create component or plugin for my'cms.Who can show me the solution create module or component or plugin same wordpress,or joomla?

Answer (score 1):

Learn PHP - the language that both Joomla and Wordpress are written in - and then learn the Joomla / Wordpress frameworks.

There are thousands of existing components for both of these, so you should check to see if someone has already written what you need.